# How to show inverse hyperbolic sine addition formulae

Tags: hyperbolic-functions, inverse-function

How to show this property
$$\mathrm{arsinh}\ x + \mathrm{arsinh}\,y = \mathrm{arsinh}\left(x\cdot\sqrt{y^2+1}+y\cdot\sqrt{x^2+1}\right)$$
I tried with log formula $\mathrm{arsinh}\,t = \ln\left(t+\sqrt{t^2+1}\right)$ but, I can't simplify this expression :
$$xy + \sqrt{y^2+1}\cdot \sqrt{x^2+1}$$
as $\sqrt{X^2 +1}$...

Thanks for help.

Comment: Have you tried the two ways aroud? From the left side to the right, and from the right to teh left? There is often an easier way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Take the $\sinh$ of both sides.

Then use the fact that $$\sinh (a+b)=\sinh (a) \cosh (b)+\cosh (a) \sinh (b)$$ compute the result for $a=\sinh ^{-1}(x)$ and $b=\sinh ^{-1}(y)$.